# Where should I locate shared @helper functions in MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a helper function that turns minutes into hours/mins.  I currently have it in my layout.cshtml but each page cannot see the function.  Where should I put the helper function such that every page can see it?

```
@helper DisplayElapsedTime(int timeInMins){
    String timeStr = "";
    if (timeInMins >= 60) {
        int hours = timeInMins/60;
        timeInMins -= hours * 60;
        timeStr = hours + "h ";
    }
    if (timeInMins > 0){
        timeStr += timeInMins + "m";
    }
    @timeStr;
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should put it into the **App_Code** folder. There is an awesome article for you to read [ASP.NET MVC Helpers](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx)

Comment: You may create it manually. It will work as expected. Just put it into the root of your MVC application and name App_Code.

Comment: I had been reading that page only a few minutes ago, must have missed this section.  Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't appear to work anymore. Create a new MVC5 project, add an App_Code folder, create a @helper library cshtml file, and it does not do whatever voodoo that it was previously doing. I wonder if they abandoned it?

Comment: @AndrewHoffman it still works, just tested it in a mvc5 project. Pay attention to filename. I have to reference it like: @<filename>.<helperName>()

Comment: People might be in the same situation like me, where this does not work. Do be aware of that you cannot mix programming languages in the App_Code folder! So if there is a cs file there you cannot add a cshtml file.Ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23.aspx

Comment: I think it still works ok in MVC 5. I've got cs files in my app_code folder, and as long as I specify the filename of the file in app_code containing the helpers, its fine, e.g. @MyFile.MyHelper()